# Batch-mode Graphene responds with status 400 "Batch requests should receive a list" to a React-Apollo request

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

GraphQL requests by the React-Apollo client (detailed below) to a Graphene-Django GraphQL server faile as `Status Code 400 Bad Request` with error message:

```
Batch requests should receive a list, but received {...
```

Why is that?

**Setup**

Got a GraphQL server (using [graphene-django](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django)) with a functioning Graph*i*QL; for example

```
query AllMsgsApp {
    allMessages {
        id
        message
    }
}
```

will yield:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allMessages": [
      {
        "id": "TWVzc2FnZVR5cGU6MQ=="
        "message": "Some message..."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The front-end is a React app (using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#getting-started)) and [apollo-client](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client), et al.

My test snippet in `App.js` is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-client-preset';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: createHttpLink({ 
    uri: 'http://localhost:8000/gql/' }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

client.query({
  query: gql`
    query AllMsgsApp {
      allMessages {
        id
        message
      }
    }
  `
}).then(response => console.log(response.data.allMessages))
```

Once `yarn start`, the response obtained is a `400 Bad Request`:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Batch requests should receive a list, but received {'operationName': 'AllMsgsApp', 'variables': {}, 'query': 'query AllMsgsApp {
  allMessages {
    id
    message
    __typename
  }
}
'}."}]}
```

**Dependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.1.4",
    "apollo-client": "^2.0.4",
    "apollo-client-preset": "^1.0.5",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.3.1",
    "graphql": "^0.12.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-apollo": "^2.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
  }
```

**Extra**

And by the way, the following:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"query": "{ allMessages { id, message } }"}' http://localhost:8000/gql
```

basically returns the same error:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Batch requests should receive a list, but received {'query': '{ allMessages { id, message } }'}."}]}
```

**However**, this one will return the expected result (notice the enclosing `[ ]`):

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[{"query": "{ allMessages { id, message } }"}]' http://localhost:8000/gql
```

which is:

```
[
  {
    "data":{
      "allMessages":[
        {
          "id":"TWVzc2FnZVR5cGU6MQ==",
          "message":"Some message..."
        }
      ]
    },
    "id":null,
    "status":200
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `createHttpLink` use the newer `BatchHttpLink`.

Import like this:

`import { BatchHttpLink } from "apollo-link-batch-http";`

and

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new BatchHttpLink({ 
    uri: 'http://localhost:8000/gql/' }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

I hope this will help. This will send the batch requests from Apollo which you are expecting from your server.